# Module not found errors after upgrading from Webpack v1 to v3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, migration

I'm trying to upgrade from Webpack v1 to v3
I've followed everything in the official migration docs, but I keep getting these errors when running `node client/scripts/start.js`. I have no idea how to fix them:

```
  Starting dev server on port 3000...

  Failed to compile.

  Error in ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'ansi-html' in '/Users/me/work/-admin/node_modules/react-dev-utils'

  @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js

  Error in multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'babel' in '/Users/me/work/-admin'

  @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js

  Error in ./client/config/polyfills.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'bluebird' in '/Users/me/work/-admin/client/config'

  @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js

  Error in ./client/config/polyfills.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'core-js/actual' in '/Users/me/work/-admin/client/config'

  @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js

  Error in ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'html-entities' in '/Users/me/work/-admin/node_modules/react-dev-utils'

  @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js

  Error in ./client/config/polyfills.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'object-assign' in '/Users/me/work/-admin/client/config'

  @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js

  Error in multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-hot-loader/patch' in '/Users/me/work/-admin'

  @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js

  Error in ./client/config/polyfills.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'regenerator-runtime/runtime' in '/Users/me/work/-admin/client/config'

  @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js

  Error in ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'sockjs-client' in '/Users/me/work/-admin/node_modules/react-dev-utils'

  @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js

  Error in ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'strip-ansi' in '/Users/me/work/-admin/node_modules/react-dev-utils'

  @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js

  Error in ./client/config/polyfills.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'whatwg-fetch' in '/Users/me/work/-admin/client/config'

  @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./client/config/polyfills.js react-hot-loader/patch ./client/src/index.js
```

I have all these deps though. The files definitely exist.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the dependencies or have bad versions of them

If it's an error in your node module, that means you have a version that is incompatible with your webpack version. Here it is saying that `react-dev-utils` is not playing nice with webpack

```bash
Error in ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
```

If the error is in a file in your project, then you are missing the dependency and need to install it

```bash
Error in ./client/config/polyfills.js
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'whatwg-fetch'
```

Install it

```
npm i --save whatwg-fetch
```

Comment: Also, webpack is already on v5 and there are some huge improvements in it since v3 came out. You should consider wiping your config clean and just starting over with a v5 one

Comment: thanks for the insight! i'm upgrading incrementally because the jump to v5 is pretty steep. i should have all these dependencies already, but i'll try upgrading them to see if it changes any of the error messages

Comment: do you think it could be a loader issue? i don't know too much about those types of configs so that was mainly what i was worried about